# Query to search multiple columns for a single value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to add a search function for my app I want it to be able search for any items where the name or the description might match the searched value.

My columns are title, description, sku etc..

So if someone searches for "green" it might return an item with the title "green cup" and it will return another item with the description "solid green shimmering plate"

```
var data = "green"
client.query('SELECT * FROM items WHERE $1 IN (upc, title, description)', [data], function(err, res){
   //return res.rows; 
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

edit: this is my whole function

```
exports.getItems = function(data, cb) {
  var client = new Client(url);
  client.connect();
  client.query('SELECT DISTINCT title, description, sku FROM items WHERE title + description + sku LIKE  %'+data+'%',  (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (res.rows.length === 0) {
      console.log("test");
      client.end();
      return cb(null, null);
    }
    console.log(res.rows);
    //cb(null, res.rows[0]);
    client.end();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more lesser code :)

**POSTGRESQL**

```
var data = "green"
client.query("SELECT DISTINCT title, description, sku FROM items WHERE title || description || sku LIKE $1", ['%'+data+'%'], function(err, res){
   //return res.rows; 
}
```

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name updated with postgressql query

Comment: I tried this, but it throws an err "syntax error at or near "%", When I remove the %'s It returns an empty rows

Comment: @EdBangga i uploaded my whole function as an edit to this post, it's still throwing the syntax error with %

Answer (score 1):

You can do `ILIKE` for case insensitive:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        items
WHERE       (upc ILIKE '%search_string%')
            OR (title ILIKE '%search_string%')
            OR (description ILIKE '%search_string%');
```

This answers your question, but you will find it very slow.

The way to speed it up is to create a column named "search_string" which has all the columns you wanted to search, added together, then build a GIN index on that. Then you can search for the value there.

Comment: this might be a newb question but is there a way to pass in a variable instead of constant string? 'search_string' could be any input. I'm used to using $1, $2, $3 for values  then setting the data [var1, var2, var3]   ... this is in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT DISTINCT title, description, sku FROM items 
       WHERE
       title LIKE '%green%' OR
       description LIKE '%green%' OR
       sku LIKE '%green%'
```

You don't want to use `SELECT * FROM items` because you will get duplicates if multiple columns match your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to provide the search string once, you can do this with a slightly more complicated query:

```
select *
from data
where exists (select *
              from unnest(array[title, description, upc]) t(c)
              where t.c ilike '%green%');
```

Of course the `'%green%'` can also be a parameter.

If you want to add additional column to be searched, just add them to the array.

However, this is **not** going to be fast, and can't be indexed either. If performance is critical consider Joseph Lee's answer and create a [trigram index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.40.7) on each of the columns.

Or maybe even consider [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) - but that depends on the exact requirements on what you want and how you want to search. FTS is usually not a good replacement for LIKE queries.